# SharePoint Core Column Name issue

Tags: content-type, column, administration, site-column

While I was creating a new content type based on Document, I accidentally renamed the core column name 'Name' to another value.

Unfortunately this has perpetuated to other content types based on this parent type.

Now I can't rename it back as the word 'Name' is reserved. Would anyone have a solution?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or On-prem?

Comment: SharePoint Online